# $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] и обновление страницы

Tags: php

Добрый день! Есть форма регистрации, на каждом этапе которой проверяться откуда пришёл пользователь (с нашего сайта, или же с совсем иного) с помощью `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]`. 
Всё бы хорошо, но вот при обновлении страницы, `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` просто остается пустым, соответственно проверку на этапе не проходит и получает ошибку.

**Как можно побороть такое, т.е. что бы даже после обновления мы знали что пользователь точно наш?**

Comment: Может, после первого прихода (если, конечно, он был правильный, то есть с вашего сайта), поставить куку сразу, и потом уже если она есть, то реферрер и не проверять.

Comment: @Construct: страницу можно сохранить, потом отправить просто не проверенные данные (они на JS проверяются).

Comment: @ka5itoshka, эмм? То есть у вас данные на PHP не проверяются? О какой тогда безопасности можно говорить?

Comment: @Construct: на php тоже проверяются, но уже не так сильно как на JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что мешает использовать или cookie, или сессии, или же **local storage**? Зашел пользователь, включили сессию. Теперь проверяем и $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER], и сессию. Если что-то из этого нас устраивает, то "милости просим"

Comment: Думал так сделать, но куки можно подменить. А сессий и без того много получается. А про local storage слышал, но мало что о нём знаю.

Comment: @ka5itoshka, почитайте про [local storage](http://todosite.ru/2011/hosting/lokalnoe-hranilishhe-local-storage-chto-eto-takoe/), ничего сложного, тем более, что с куками и сессиями вы знакомы.

Comment: Можно всё таки с сессиями попробывать (но я не знаю, будет ли это безопасным):
при каждом клике на submit, ajax'ом проверяем есть ли пользователь в бд и заодно при true проверке добавляем в специальную сессию +1, при false ничего не добавляем. А на шагах просто проверяем кол-во в специальной сессии. 
Что скажите, безопасно так делать? Просто опять таки, пользователь может сохранить страницу и не пройти js проверку а просто отправить ajax запрос.

Comment: Я не знаю все тонкости вашей задачи, как знаете их вы. Поэтому ваши рассуждения меня ни к чему не подталкивают )) Что значит "безопасно так делать"? В чем собственно опасность?

Comment: @Deonis, опасность в подмене данных (так я считаю)))

Answer (score 0):

Используйте csrf токен, что бы человек не смог заранее предугодать его не находясь на соответствующей форме страницы. http://habrahabr.ru/post/235247/ есть статья на хабе неплохая по вашей теме. Суть проста человек заходит на страницу формы авторизованный в системе, при загрузке страницы генериться ключ токен в скрытом поле, и записываеться в сессию. Если они не совпадают значит запрос не с вашего сайта.